# How to extract lines between two patterns using lines in between as a printing condition

Tags: regex, awk, multiline

I'm searching for a way to use the following code as a basis

```
function get { 
  awk '/^\[ '"$1"' \]/{p=1;next} /^$/{p=0} p' "${MY_FILE_PATH}"
}
```

to extract a complete section of `myfile`:

```
[ SECTION_1 ]
info 1
info 2
info 3

[ SECTION_2 ]
info 4
info 5
info 6
```

conditioned on the entries it has.

When I'm asking for `info 2` for example, it should print the complete `SECTION_1`.
I thought of using additional flags, but I did not get the desired results.

Is there any solution that can be derived from the function `get` above to achieve this behavior?

Thanks for tipps and hints :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can this awk with `RS=`:

```
awk -v s="SECTION_1" -v RS= '$0 ~ "\\[ " s " \\]"' file
[ SECTION_1 ]
info 1
info 2
info 3
```

Or using `info 2` as **search string**:

```
awk -v s="info 2" -v RS= '$0 ~ s' file
[ SECTION_1 ]
info 1
info 2
info 3
```

Comment: Ok, then I have to be more precise. I want to print out only that section (including all its values) that contains a specific value. You won't now the sections name before!

Comment: The second one gives exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thanks! Would be great to give a short explaination about what this exactly does :)

Comment: Yes sure, glad it worked. Main trick here is use of `RS=` which sets **record separator** as null thus making whole section till blank line as one record. Doing this allows us to search anywhere in the section using `info 1` or `info 2` etc.